# Merge [alpr] and [anpr]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I think we should merge [alpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpr) and [anpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anpr).

Both tags are about automatically detecting/reading *license plates* on vehicles. In some places of the world, license plates, for some reason, are called "number plates", a blander term, even though there aren't just numbers on these plates.

In the interest of [bikeshedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality) and clarity, I'd recommend to keep ALPR and make ANPR the synonym.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have [automatic-license-plate-recognition] as a tag, with both abbreviations as synonyms?

Comment: probably a good idea. I don't know where this community leans on the "brevity" vs "self-explanatory" spectrum. people dealing with ALPR/ANPR certainly treat these four-letter words as terms in themselves :>

Comment: Do we even need a tag for automatic license plate recognition? If we create a tag for each and any object that could be recognized on an image, that would easily get out of hand.

Comment: since [wikipedia has an article on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_number-plate_recognition#Algorithms), I would recommend leaning towards keeping it.